# what are the steps to add in jenkins file for scanning the image that pushed into ECR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-ecr

need to scan the image that are being pushed to ECR before deployment. So I need to add this step into existing pipeline

I am just trying to add this scanning image step into existing pipeline

Comment: Scanning for security vulnerabilities? What tools are you planning to use? Also, ECR has [built-in scanning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/image-scanning.html) that you can enable, where the images get scanned periodically. That way, you don't have to integrate scanning separately.

Comment: yes. i need to scan for vulnerabilities. I am using jenkins only. after building my image, I need to push it into ECR and then scan those images for vulnerability. I wanted to include this step in my pipeline. only if the scan results are positive, deployment should happen

Comment: You can use [snyk](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/snyk-security-scanner/) to scan your image from the pipeline.